# PrimeNG Dropdown: Overriding the styles to hide input and label elements

Tags: css, angular, dropdown, primeng

I am new to PrimeNG, need to either remove the input and label elements or hide them with CSS, I understand that ViewEncapsulation set to None is not a good workaround. As of now all I have is a basic component so I think we don't need any snapshot of the code?

Comment: As in, you want to hide them in existing ngprime components that you don't want to edit the ngprime source to do? Or elements you're adding? Can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. Setting the ViewEncapsulation to none is not a good practice. You can use `::ng-deep` in your css. Be aware that `::ng-deep` will go away in the future. I don't know when.

Example:

```
::ng-deep{
    .x-page-wrapper{
        height: 100%;
    }

}
```